# Jenkins Distributed Builds: virtual machines for master / agents

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to understand Jenkins distributed builds. From what I have read, Jenkins master uses its' own JVM, and each agent / slave uses its' own JVM.

My Jenkins master is running on a machine with an Ubuntu 16.04 native OS. Am I correct in assuming that each master and agent / slave will have it's own JVM (as oppose to their own linux virtual machines)?

Am I also correct in assuming that once Jenkins master is installed and running, the Jenkins master will orchestrate spinning up the additional JVMs required for the Jenkins agent / slaves?

Thank you for any help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those agents/slaves should run not on the same system (aka VM) as the master. I guess they could, but there wouldn't be any benefits (which is usually: compute power).

If you want more simultaneous builds, add additional machines that have a JVM installed, where the Jenkins Master will launch its slaves (aka agents).

Comment: So just to apply this to my particular use case: A machine with Ubuntu 16.04 as the native OS in which Jenkins is installed and running should also have Virtualbox installed on it in order to launch the slaves / agents, or all slaves / agents should have their own machine completely different from the Jenkins master?

Comment: Actually, the should run on different physical machines. You can't give your build jobs more power through VMs on one host. But it sounds a bit like you don't have that much workload, yet. So maybe just drop the idea of slaves and start with the master only. Once you're familiar with Jenkins and need more horse power, add more slaves.

Comment: Great advice! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. From what I've seen online the entry point to getting Jenkins up and running is usually a single master which over time has slaves / agents added to it as workload increases. That's good to know though for future planning that the Jenkins Master and Jenkins slaves / agents should be on separate physical machines.